# SignIn / Consent Window does not close on mobile

Tags: oauth, hello.js

I have a web app eg www.webapp.com that uses Hello.js to sign in users. It works from the desktop and mobile devices as long as I use the **browser** to navigate to the site.

PROBLEM: I can install it to the device (eg "Add to Homescreen" on Android or iOS). But when I run it from the homescreen, the authentication/consent screen gets stuck on a blank page and a "connecting" message. My manifest.json file has display: standalone

I have to **manually** close the popup, and use the "Back" button on the phone to get back to the login screen. The response token etc. are there as expected. Why is the popup screen not closing? How can it be forced to close without user intervention?

Is there anything that can be done to make it work with HTML5 "installed" apps?

Comment: That's an interesting one, can you raise a ticket in HelloJS? And attach additional information, like the full URL including the hash fragment which it is stuck on (please obfuscate your access_token)